# How to Limit Variable Scope

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Limiting variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277556/limiting-variable-scope)

Is there a way to force R to ignore all objects set in the global environment? For example, let's say I have 'df' as an object outside of my function and I wish to use the same shorthand within my function, but not in reference to the object in the global environment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this question: ["Limiting variable scope"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277556/limiting-variable-scope).

Answer (score 2):

So what? The df in your function won't be the global df.

```
> df = 1
> foo = function(x){df=x*2;return(df)}
```

Now when you do foo(df) the df inside the function isn't the global df. So what's your problem? I guess it can only be a problem if you want the global df inside your function as well, in which case:

- don't use globals in functions - it breaks the functional style
- use a different name if it's a different thing.