# how to isolate a function

Tags: r

How can I ensure that when a function is called it is not allowed to grab variables from the global environment?

I would like the following code to give me an error. The reason is because I might have mistyped z (I wanted to type y).

```
z <- 10
temp <- function(x,y) {
        y <- y + 2
        return(x+z)
}
> temp(2,1)
[1] 12
```

I'm guessing the answer has to do with environments, but I haven't understood those yet.

Is there a way to make my desired behavior default (e.g. by setting an option)?

Comment: There is some discussion in the February 27, 2010 news item on the proto home page: http://r-proto.googlecode.com .

Comment: @G.Grothendieck thank you, that looks interesting. I'm not sure I feel like digging into such a big package/change of philosophy yet. But I will keep this in mind once I get more experience.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has already been asked here.

Comment: @hadley I bet you're right. I didn't know the terminology I needed to search for it though. If I find any duplicates/similars I will post the relevant links here, or mark mine as a duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [R force local scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216968/r-force-local-scope)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
> library(codetools)
> checkUsage(temp)
<anonymous>: no visible binding for global variable 'z'
```

The function doesn't change, so no need to check it each time it's used. `findGlobals` is more general, and a little more cryptic. Something like

```
Filter(Negate(is.null), eapply(.GlobalEnv, function(elt) {
    if (is.function(elt))
        findGlobals(elt)
}))
```

could visit all functions in an environment, but if there are several functions then maybe it's time to think about writing a package (it's not that hard).

Comment: thanks! That looks like a great function. However, you still have to worry about environments it appears. ie, if I copy and insert all of the code in my original post and then run `checkUsage(temp)` it will not report an error. I need to copy only the function `temp`.

Comment: see `findGlobals` and the help pages for the package.

Comment: ok I will check that out. How can I run checkUsage on all functions in ls() ? Or if that's difficult, assuming there are only functions output by ls(), how can I run checkUsage on all of them? I tried `lapply(ls(),FUN = checkUsage)` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

```
environment(temp) = baseenv()
```

See also http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Scope-of-variables and `?environment`.

Comment: It will mask all but variables in base environment. i.e., add-on packages are not available within the `temp`.

Comment: and how would I mask everything except `base` and, say, the `plyr` package?

Comment: Not sure but maybe `environment(temp) <- new.env(parent = as.environment(search()[2]))` will mask only the global environment.

Answer (score 2):

```
environment(fun) = parent.env(environment(fun))
```

(I'm using 'fun' in place of your function name 'temp' for clarity)

This will remove the "workspace" environment (.GlobalEnv) from the search path and leave everything else (eg all packages).