# R & Makefile: how to inherit dependencies?

Tags: r, makefile, dependency-management

I use a `Makefile` to byte-compile my `R` files (mostly to detect potential problems with the code). When compiling a file, I load its `library` requirements and `loadcmp` its local dependencies:

```
R = R --quiet
MISC_REQ = entropy igraph data.table
misc.Rc : REQ = $(MISC_REQ)
import.Rc : import.R misc.Rc
import.Rc : REQ = $(MISC_REQ)
modeling-functions.Rc : modeling-functions.R misc.Rc
modeling-functions.Rc : REQ = $(MISC_REQ) plyr Matrix e1071

%.Rc : %.R
    $(R) $(foreach f,$(REQ),-e 'library("$f")') \
        $(foreach f,$(filter %.Rc, $^),-e 'loadcmp("$f")') \
        -e 'source("$<"); cmpfile("$<"); checkUsageEnv(.GlobalEnv)'
```

I wonder if there is a way for me to avoid specifying the dependency *twice*: once when I mention that `import.Rc` depends on `misc.Rc` and the second time when I add `MISC_REQ` to `REQ` for `import.Rc`.

EDIT:
for my very simple dependency tree, I can get away with the following simplification:

```
REQ = entropy igraph data.table
misc.Rc :
share-click-import.Rc : share-click-import.R misc.Rc
modeling-functions.Rc : modeling-functions.R misc.Rc
modeling-functions.Rc : REQ += plyr Matrix e1071
```

However, I would like a more general solution.

Automatic dependency detection along the lines of `omake` would be nice.

Comment: I posted my answer below, but wanted to ask why are you compiling your files in this way? How do you "detect potential problems with the code"?

Comment: @Michal: `checkUsageEnv` and `cmpfile` report unused and undefined variables.

Comment: I did a quick search, and couldn't find any static analysis tools for R either.

Comment: nvm, there's the `codetools` package available for R that I think can solve your problem within the R runtime: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216968/r-force-local-scope

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is any sensible way to do that. Notice that even though you call both things "dependencies", only the first one (import.Rc: import.R misc.Rc) is actually a dependency in the sense of Make. The second thing is setting a target-specific variable. I'm afraid it is impossible to set both things within a single rule.

In principle you could write a function, say 'gendeps', that could generate the rules for you, but to me it seems its overly complicated and boils down to typing-in exactly the same information. Anyway, the function could look like:

```
# Generate dependency rules
# usage:
#  $(eval $(call gendeps,targetfile,prerequisites,packages))
define gendeps
$1: $2

$1: REQ+=$3
endef
```

and then use it as, say:

```
$(eval $(call gendeps,misc.Rc,import.R misc.R,plyr))
```

This will make import.R a prerequisite of misc.Rc and add the plyr package to the list of required packages.

In your example you could also set the default value for REQ

```
REQ=$(MISC_REQ)
```

and drop the target-specific setting for import.Rc and misc.Rc

Comment: user-defined function does _not_ sound like an overkill to me! also, see edit

Comment: ok, I edited the answer by adding the example of `gendeps` function