# Utility for checking source file(s) for errors

Tags: r

When developing a package one can run `R CMD check`, which helpfully tells you any problems in your code (syntax errors, unstated dependencies, undefined variables).

Does a utility exist that will provide this functionality of `R CMD check` for individual source files?

I could create an empty package and move source files in their to check them, but that's both a pain, and overkill.

Comment: Not quite a duplicate, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216968/r-force-local-scope may be of usage for at least part of this....

Comment: You can check for syntax errors with `parse(file='myfilename')`.

Comment: Can you expand? All it gives me is a string where each newline in the file is separated by a comma.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to look at the codetools package.

Comment: After reading that package I don't suppose it's possible for R to read a file and apply `checkUsage`.  I could wrap everything in function(s) load, and check before running.