# R package can see variables not passed to it

Tags: r

I am writing a new R package and find that variables that I have not explicitly passed to a function in the package (as input argument) are visible within it, e.g.:

```
myFunc <- function(a,b,c) {
  print(d)
}
```

where `d` is in the caller `.R` script, but has not been passed to `myFunc`, is visible.

Any help would be great, thanks; I'm using R 3.2.4 and have been using `roxygen2` (via `devtools::document()`) to create the `NAMESPACE` if that helps.

Comment: Does this behavior happen after the package has been installed, or only during the development / testing process?

Comment: I see it after the package is installed, i.e. after running `R CMD INSTALL myPackage` and then having a .R script outside the package call `myFunc()`.

Comment: This is due to R's scoping rules. There is a new package `modules` on CRAN which helps to address this common issue. See more details in my answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216968/r-force-local-scope?lq=1

Comment: @ShraddhaPai I posted today a new answer to the thread you were linked to, you may find there some more convenient functions

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this just a consequence of the scoping rules in R?

Your function defines a new `myFunc` environment.  When you try to reference `d` in `print(d)`, the interpreter first checks the `myFunc` environment for an object called `d`.  Because no such object exists, the interpreter next checks the calling environment for an object called `d`.  It finds the variable defined in your .R script and then prints it.

Here's [a link](http://www.programiz.com/r-programming/environment-scope) with more info and a pile of examples.

Answer (score 0):

Very useful link, thanks. It looks like forcing limited scoping within a function (i.e. getting a function to not access the global scope) is not a default property of R.

I found a similar question here: [R force local scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216968/r-force-local-scope)

Using the `checkStrict` function posted by the main responder to that question seems to have worked; it found an unintended use of a global variable.

```
> require(myCustomPackage)
> checkStrict(showDendro)
Warning message:
In checkStrict(showDendro) : global variables used: palName
```

where `showDendro` is a function inside my custom package.

So it seems the solution to my problem is:

1) while you can stop R from moving up to the global environment by enclosing all your functions in the `local()` function , that seems like a tedious solution.

2) when moving code from the general environment into its own function, run something like `checkStrict` to remove unintended use of global variables.