# Force R function call to be self-sufficient

Tags: r, scoping, environments

I'm looking for a way to call a function that is not influenced by other objects in `.GlobalEnv`.

Take a look at the two functions below:

```
y = 3
f1 = function(x) x+y

f2 = function(x) {
   library(dplyr)
   x %>%
       mutate(area = Sepal.Length *Sepal.Width) %>%
       head()
}
```

In this case:

- `f1(5)` should fail, because `y` is not defined in the function scope
- `f2(iris)` should pass, because the function does not reference variables outside its scope

Now, I can overwrite the environment of `f1` and `f2`, either to `baseenv()` or `new.env(parent=environment(2L))`:

```
environment(f1) = baseenv()
environment(f2) = baseenv()
f1(3)    # fails, as it should
f2(iris) # fails, because %>% is not in function env
```

or:

```
# detaching here makes `dplyr` inaccessible for `f2`
# not detaching leaves `head` inaccessible for `f2`
detach("package:dplyr", unload=TRUE)
environment(f1) = new.env(parent=as.environment(2L))
environment(f2) = new.env(parent=as.environment(2L))
f1(3)    # fails, as it should
f2(iris) # fails, because %>% is not in function env
```

Is there a way to overwrite a function's environment so that it has to be self-sufficient, but it also always works as long as it loads its own libraries?

Comment: As long as it is what?

Comment: Honestly, I just wouldn't write functions that included global variables at all--it seems like a recipe for unintended errors.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6216968/324364

Comment: @be_green I’m like 99.9% sure that Michael not only knows this but strongly agrees. I don’t know the context of the question but I guess it has something to do with isolating self-contained user code in a [library that performs cross-machine communication](https://github.com/mschubert/clustermq).

Comment: @be_green The question is to *specifically guard against* usage of global variables

Comment: @joran This is indeed equivalent to my approach #2, but Konrad describes why it doesn't work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8175014/538603

Comment: @MichaelSchubert oh sorry, I must have misunderstood

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is, fundamentally, that `library` and similar tools don’t provide scoping, and are not designed to be made to work with scopes:<sup>1</sup> Even though `library` is executed inside the function, its effect is actually global, not local. *Ugh.*

Specifically, your approach of isolating the function from the global environment is sounds; however, `library` manipulates the `search` path (via `attach`), and the function’s environment isn’t “notified” of this: it will still point to the *previous* second search path entry as its grandparent.

You need to find a way of *updating* the function environment’s grandparent environment when `library`/`attach`/… ist called. You could achieve this by replacing `library` etc. in the function’s parent environment with your own versions that calls a modified version of `attach`. This `attach2` would then not only call the original `attach` but also relink your environment’s parent.

---

<sup>1</sup> As an aside, ‘[box](https://klmr.me/box/)’ fixes all of these problems. Replacing `library(foo)` with `box::use(foo[...])` in your code makes it work. This is because modules are strongly scoped and environment-aware.

Comment: Yes, it looks like there is no other way. But for this to work, this overwritten version of `library` would need to be attached, which I'm not sure I can enforce for local code due to potential unintended side effects.