# r how to remove all side effects to the calls to the library() inside the function?

Tags: r, encapsulation

I would like to run my functions in the special environment, which does not include any of the objects available in the global environment (for debugging purposes)

Unfortunately, I cannot run them in the `baseenv()` (or any other  environment that doesn't include the global environment among its parents), using the `local(func_name(...), envir=baseenv())` because calls to the `library` made inside the function would do nothing, because `library()` only modifies the parent of the  `globalenv()`.

Is there any solution?

edit:

There is a related question [R force local scope](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6216968/1261153) with more general nature that doesn't deal with the `library()` calls.

Comment: @akrun Not really a duplicate. I specifically ask about the `library()` calls, while the question you refer doesn't mention this, and neither the answers. Thank you for finding that question though. I will mention it in the text, but please remove the duplication tag.

Comment: I will remove the dupe tag.  It was actually tagged by somebody else first