# Making R return an error for accessing a global

Tags: r, scope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Limiting variable scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277556/limiting-variable-scope)

One of the easiest errors for me to slip into is having a function access a variable that is in the global environment as opposed to the local environment.  During development, this might happen when I change the name of a variable and forget to `rm` the old one--then fail to update a function to make it access the new one.

Is there a way to have R return an error or warning whenever it automatically grabs a variable from higher up in the tree?  It seems like this would be easier now that R supports compiled code....

Here's a quickie example of what I'd like to return an error/warning:

```
x <- 5
f <- function(y) {
   z <- y + x
   z
}
f(3)  #will return 8
```

Comment: Do either of these questions help: [Limiting variable scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277556/limiting-variable-scope), [R force local scope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216968/r-force-local-scope)?

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich The second one is the one I was looking for.  Voted to close in the interests of keeping all the good answers consolidated in one place.

Comment: I've tackled this problem by testing my functions in clean R sessions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's an easy way (e.g. an option in `options()`). Are your functions in an R script file? Are you building a package?

If so, I think the best way is:

```
> f <- function(y) {
+    z <- y + x
+    z
+ }
> library(codetools)
> checkUsage(f)
<anonymous>: no visible binding for global variable ‘x’ (:2)
```

But note that if `z` is defined then this will not find an error. You would have to copy your `f` function into a new R session and then run `checkUsage`. This seems like a pain but it's not that bad and I'm sure you could create some tricks for dealing with it. And if you have your functions all in a separate file then it's easy.

Comment: This seems like the proper way, but it both requires me to actively call `checkUsage` each time, and doesn't really work on one-off anonymous functions in e.g. sapply calls....

Comment: @gsk3 I'm not sure anything can fix one-offs, but running `checkUsage` is a good idea for package and script development.

Answer (score 1):

`f()` fails because there is not a default value for `y`.  I think you meant `f(1)`.

There may be a better way to do this, but you could wrap your function definitions in `local` calls during development.  Something like:

```
x <- 5
f <- local(function(y) {
   z <- y + x
   z
}, baseenv())
f(1)
# Error in f(1) : object 'x' not found
```

Comment: Oops.  f(1) was indeed what I meant.  I like the idea of the local wrapper.  Is there a way to overload the `function` function so that this doesn't have to be done for every function, and then un-done again when development "ceases" (as though it ever stops!).

Answer (score 1):

It is always a good idea to throw your functions into a package. That has the added advantage of allowing for R CMD check. One of the checks that R performs is dependencies on variables (this was referenced to in e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8096313/709529)).

Of course, truth be told, while actually developing, constantly rebuilding and checking and reinstalling your package is somewhat of a hassle, so you may be better off with the other suggestions.